# C#: How to avoid WIA-error when scanning documents with 2400dpi or more?

Tags: c#, .net, wia, image-scanner

when we scan a document with a resolution of 2400dpi or higher, we recieve (for example) the following error-message:

COMException: Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80010100 (RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED)

or

COMException: Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8021006F

in one of the following lines

```
            img = itm.Transfer(scanFormat.ScanFormat) as WIA.ImageFile;
            img = ip.Apply(img as WIA.ImageFile);
```

some screenshots for the mentioned errors:

http://www.amarant-it.de/TempDownload/WIA_Error01.png

or the same path with WIA_Error02.png and WIA_Error03.png

for scanning we use the following code:

```
            #region Image-Convert-Settings
            //IP.Filters.Add IP.FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID
            //IP.Filters(1).Properties("FormatID").Value = wiaFormatJPEG
            WIA.IImageProcess ip = new WIA.ImageProcessClass();
            object convert = "Convert";
            WIA.IFilterInfo fi = ip.FilterInfos.get_Item(ref convert);
            ip.Filters.Add(fi.FilterID, 0);
            convert = "FormatID";
            object formatstring = scanFormat.ScanFormat;
            WIA.IFilter filter;
            foreach (WIA.IFilter fTemp in ip.Filters)
            {
                filter = fTemp;
                WIA.IProperty prop = filter.Properties.get_Item(ref convert);
                prop.set_Value(ref formatstring);
            }
            #endregion
            #region Image-Scan + Convert
            img = itm.Transfer(scanFormat.ScanFormat) as WIA.ImageFile;
            img = ip.Apply(img as WIA.ImageFile);
            img.SaveFile("D:\\scan2." + img.FileExtension);
            Image image = Image.FromFile("D:\\scan2." + img.FileExtension);
            ilImages.Images.Add(image.ToString(), image);
            alImages.Add(image);
            if (ImageScanned != null)
            {
                ImageScanned(image);
            }
            #endregion
```

can anyone help us with this problem?

thanks

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this??? i'm having the same issue here!!!

Comment: still this error ... just hide the selection > 1600 dpi for the users :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you're doing A4/8.5x11 in color (32-bit) - that's very close to 2 gig for a BMP, which is close to the limit of a 32-bit signed number.  I'd say it's not so much resolution but total data size. At least limits of the COM data structures is the conclusion of this author of a [silverlight scan application](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/04/14/scanning-an-image-from-silverlight-4-using-wia-automation).  If you think about it, if it ever all shows up in a buffer for a 32-bit process, you'll run out of memory trying to allocate a contiguous chunk of memory that big.

My WIA knowledge has faded a bit, but if I recall correctly, WIA scans via a service, if it's 32-bit and you're calling it via COM, that's where the buffer and the limit comes from.  That and if you don't get the scan parameters just right, it'll pick BMP (no compression).  I can't seem to recall if you can get it to do JPEG for color or if you're forced to go through a converter.  If you want to work with data that's this big, one option could be is to switch to the C++ api, which allows streamed instead of buffered access (I've never used it but I mentioned it in case it helps).